# How to select an item from the dropdown list through selenium webdriver and java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, dropdown

Update: 
I want to be able to click on the options available example in the HTML code. There are two options (id="all_setup_home" and id="developer-console-link"). Currently, the XPath I am utilizing clicks randomly on the dropdown and it takes me to the option 1 page (that's what i want) but it is not very dynamic as my XPath does not target option 1 or 2 but the drop-down. And so if I want to click on the second option I will not be able to.

Anything better than this would be much appreciated.

The workaround that's working for now:

```html
getElementByXPath("Settings").click();
Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[contains(@class,'scrollable')]")).click();
```

Inital work that is still not working:

```html
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

HTML

```html
<div class="popupTargetContainer menu--nubbin-top uiPopupTarget uimenuList uiMenuList--right uimenuList--default visible positioned" data-aura-rendered-by="101:185;a" data-aura-class="uiPopupTarget uimenuList uimenuList--right uimenuList--default" aria-labelledby="59:185;a">
  ::before
  <div role="menu" data-aura-rendered-by="95:184;a">
    <!--render facet:96:184;a-->
    <ul class="scrollable" role="presentation" data-aura-rendered-by="97:184;a">
      <!--render facet: 816:0-->
      <!--render facet: 882:0-->
      <li class="slds-dropdown__item uiMenuItem onesetupSetupMenuItem" role="presentation" id="all_setup_home" data-aura-rendered-by="893:0" data-aura-class="uiMenuItem onesetupSetupMenuItem">....</li>
      <!--render facet:826:0-->
      <!--render facet:2004:0-->
      <li class="slds-dropdown__item uiMenuItem onesetupSetupMenuItem" role="presentation" id="developer-console-link" data-aura-rendered-by="893:0" data-aura-class="uiMenuItem onesetupSetupMenuItem">....</li>
      <!--render facet:826:0-->
      <!--render facet:2004:0-->
```

Comment: IMO, somehow you have truncated the HTML beyond repair and constructing an effective answer is nearly impossible. Update the question with text based formatted HTML please.

Comment: Your HTML is incorrect, the very first `<div` tag contains **2** _class_ attributes as `popupTargetContainer menu--nubbin-top uiPopupTarget uimenuList uiMenuList--right uimenuList--default
visible positioned` and `uiPopupTarget uimenuList uiMenuList--right
uiMenuList--default`

Comment: I have updated the HTML code, can you look into it now.

Comment: IMO, your HTML is still incorrect as the first `<div>` still contains the attribute `data-aura-class` **twice** as in **data-aura-class="uiMenuItem"** and **data-aura-class="uiPopupTarget uimenuList uimenuList--right uimenuList--default"**

Comment: I have updated so should be good now.

Comment: Where are you exactly stuck? Is the dropdown opening up as per your code trials?

Comment: Yes, the dropdown is opening however the xpath that I created for li's is not recognized. eg: li[contains(@id,'all-setup-home.slds-dropdown__item.uiMenuItem.onesetupSetupMenuItem')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was able to click on the first option getting the XPath from this element:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[contains(@class,'scrollable')]")).click();
```

However, this isn't very dynamic as I am unable to click on the second option.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, I don't use selenium so I cannot write the code for you but after your dropdown.click(); you have to wait a little moment, cause at the moment you do not wait for the list to be open.

Comment: I added Thread.sleep 3 to 5 seconds after dropdown.click() however it still is not working.

Comment: Ok then to be sure it is not a selector mistake you can use ctrl+shift+i and then inspect your element then right click -> copy selector

Comment: This is what I get as a selector: #oneHeader > div.slds-global-header.slds-grid.slds-grid--align-spread > span > ul > li:nth-child(7) > div > div > div.popupTargetContainer.menu--nubbin-top.uiPopupTarget.uiMenuList.uiMenuList--right.uiMenuList--default > div > ul

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment as you are able to open the dropdown next as per the HTML you have shared to select an item from the dropdown you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the items to render within the [**HTML DOM**](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) and you can use the following code block :

```
String value = "all-setup_home";
WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='slds-icon_container slds-icon-utility-setup slds-button__icon slds-global-header__icon']"));
dropdown.click();
List<WebElement> options = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//div[@class='popupTargetContainer menu--nubbin-top uiPopupTarget uimenuList uiMenuList--right uimenuList--default visible positioned']/div[@role='menu']/ul[@class='scrollable']//li[@class='slds-dropdown__item uiMenuItem onesetupSetupMenuItem']")));
for (WebElement option : options)
{
    if (option.getAttribute("innerHTML").equals(value))
    {
        option.click();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response to all my concerns however this did not help. The xpath you suggested is invalid since it does not recognize the option, which I am struggling with. As soon as i click outside of the dropdown, the elements related to the options disapears causing more frustration.